# Develop a network layer protocol in C

Tags: c, network-protocols

I wish to develop a custom network layer protocol. I suppose it can be done using C. Can any one suggest how to begin with. Any references or sample code would be of great help.

Comment: Designing a protocol is very much different from implementing one. Ideally you'd design it well enough such that it can be implemented in any language.

Comment: What kind of protocol? What kind of interoperability requirements are we talking about? Does it need to be extensible for interoperability with future versions? Or for third-party extensions? Is this a private protocol for your application or are you planning on standardizing it?

Answer (score 6):

If you're wanting to develop a custom protocol sample code isn't really going to help! You must first design your protocol.

- What is the purpose of this network?
  File Sharing, Commands, Other?
- What can connect to this network?
  Computer, Printer, Other?
- How will devices communicate?
  Messages, Codes, Other?
- What will a message or command
  consist of?

These are all valid questions you must ask yourself when you design. After your design is done, then you can start writing the actual implementation. A task like this will require a lot of design though. Forewarned..

Answer (score 1):

Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated volume 2](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv2.html) has most of the source for the higher layers in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [x-kernel](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/projects/xkernel/) project.  "The x-kernel is an object-based framework for implementing network protocols."

I stumbled over this one several years ago.  I'd talked to Don Batory at UT Austin about his research on Product Line Architectures.  At one point, I asked him if anyone was looking at doing something similar for network protocols, and he pointed me at the x-kernel work.